# Replacement with regular expression and capture

Tags: ruby, regex

The method below is supposed to transform `"snake_case"` to `"CamelCase"`.

```
def zebulansNightmare(string)
  string.gsub(/_(.)/){$1.upcase}
end
```

With string `"camel_case"`, I expect `gsub(/_(.)/)` to match `c` after the `_`. I understood that `$1` is the first matched letter: the capital letter. But it works like it's substituting `_` with the capital letter. Why has the `_` disappeared?

Comment: It is no wonder `_` gets removed: you replace the whole match with the uppercased value captured into Group 1.

Comment: Where in the document does it say that `gsub` replaces `$1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that `$1` is the captured value, however, the `gsub` matches the letter with `_` before it, and the whole match gets replaced. You need to reinsert `_` to the result:

```
"camel_case".gsub(/_(.)/){"_#{$1.upcase}"}
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/9zDcy2)

BTW, if you only plan to match `_` followed with a *letter* (so as not to waste time and resources on trying to turn non-letters to upper case), you can use the following regex:

```
/_(\p{Ll})/
```

Where `\p{Ll}` is any lowercase Unicode letter.

Answer (score 1):

```
def zebulans_nightmare(string)
  string.gsub(/\B_[a-z0-9]/) { |s| s[1].upcase }
end

zebulans_nightmare("case_of_snakes")
  #=> "caseOfSnakes" 
zebulans_nightmare("case_of_3_snakes")
  #=> "caseOf3Snakes" 
zebulans_nightmare("_case_of_3_snakes")
  #=> "_caseOf3Snakes"
```

`\B` [matches non-word boundaries](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Regexp.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answear - I don't really get it - why first character after '_' has index 1? It seems like '_' has index 0, but why, considering '_' being after '\B' in our regex?

Comment: I don't understand your references to indices, but `\B` is there only to avoid capitalizing "c" in "_case_of_snakes" (assuming that's what you want).

Comment: My problem is how indexes work in this example :) is [0] first matched character?

Comment: I see. `s` in the block will always be a two-character  string that begins with "_". `s[1]` therefore returns the character that follows that underscore.

Comment: Thank you, I get it now!